# Need help with adding custom wordpress menu and sub-menu

Tags: theme-development, menus, navigation

I've got my HTML Custom Nav set up and it works fine for static template. I want to convert it into wordpress navigation menu. I am totally new to wordpress and i want help to convert html menu to wordpress.

Here is the HTML code :

```
<div id="cs-header-menu">
                <div class="cs-container">
                    <!-- Main navigation -->
                    <div class="cs-toggle-main-navigation"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div>
                    <nav id="cs-main-navigation" class="cs-clearfix">
                        <ul class="cs-main-navigation cs-clearfix">
                            <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="#"><span>Homepages</span></a>
                                <ul class="sub-menu">
                                    <li><a href="index-1.html">Homepage 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index-2.html">Homepage 2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index-3.html">Homepage 3</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index-4.html">Homepage 4</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="blog_layout_1.html">Lifestyle</a></li>
                            <li><a href="blog_layout_1.html">Beauty</a></li>
                            <li><a href="blog_layout_1.html">Travel</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                    <!-- Search icon show -->
                    <div id="cs-header-menu-search-button-show"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
                    <!-- Search icon -->
                    <div id="cs-header-menu-search-form">
                        <div id="cs-header-menu-search-button-hide"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></div>
                        <form>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Type and press enter...">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I don't know how to use class and ids for div, nav, ul and li, and also for sub-menu items. Would anyone please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this code bellow to dynamic you nav:**

```
                        <?php
                            $args = array(
                            'theme_location'    => '',
                            'menu'              => 'Main',
                            'container'         => 'false',
                            'container_class'   => '',
                            'container_id'      => '',
                            'menu_class'        => 'cs-main-navigation cs-clearfix',
                            'menu_id'           => '',
                            'echo'              => true,
                            'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_page_menu',
                            'before'            => '',
                            'after'             => '',
                            'link_before'       => '',
                            'link_after'        => '',
                            'items_wrap'        => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
                            'depth'             => 0,
                            //'walker'            => new my_custom_walker_nav_menu()
                            );

                        wp_nav_menu ($args);
                                  ?>
                    </nav>
                    <!-- Search icon show -->
                    <div id="cs-header-menu-search-button-show"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
                    <!-- Search icon -->
                    <div id="cs-header-menu-search-form">
                        <div id="cs-header-menu-search-button-hide"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></div>
                        <form>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Type and press enter...">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

For more details please see [This](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/function-examination-wp_nav_menu--wp-25525) ..... Hope it will solve your problem

Comment: Thank you for the help, and would you please guide me, what to do with function.php file.

Comment: Just check if this code is exist or not into you functions.php if not then copy and paste the code bellow into your functions.php :                                                                             // This theme uses wp_nav_menu() in two locations.                                  
register_nav_menus( array(
    'primary' => __( 'Primary', 'twentysixteen' ),
) );

Comment: yes register_nav_menus is there, the code works well but class for ul is not working. and i have already set css for those classes, but the css is not working for menu, will you please let me know the problem?

Comment: It's working for me fine. I think you missed something. Would you please create menu again from your admin panel ? I think it will solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="cs-header-menu">
    <div class="cs-container">
        <!-- Main navigation -->
        <div class="cs-toggle-main-navigation"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div>
            <nav id="cs-main-navigation" class="cs-clearfix">
                    <?php
                        wp_nav_menu( array(
                            'theme_location' => 'primary',
                            'container'     => '',
                            'menu_class'     => 'cs-main-navigation cs-clearfix"',
                         ) );
                    ?>
            </nav>
            <!-- Search icon show -->
            <div id="cs-header-menu-search-button-show"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
            <!-- Search icon -->
            <div id="cs-header-menu-search-form">
                <div id="cs-header-menu-search-button-hide"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></div>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Type and press enter...">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

in wordpress we have a [wp_nav_menu](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) function that can get the navigation menu. For this you have to do register the menu
i.e. [register_nav_menus](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_nav_menu/). The above code fetch the primary navigation you have registered like below on the function.php file.

```
// This theme uses wp_nav_menu() in two locations.
register_nav_menus( array(
    'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'twentysixteen' ),
) );
```

You can add/remove/arrange/ the menu page on the Apperance->Menus and assign that to the Primary Menu. 
     Hope that helps!!